# Excel SUMPRODUCT and ROW Function Error

Tags: excel, function

I keep getting a #NAME? error with this function:

```
=1/A5*SUMPRODUCT((IF(FLOOR((GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24)),1)=GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24),1,0)*EulerPhi(ROW(1:24))*COMBIN(A5/ROW(1:24),B4/ROW(1:24))))
```

(EulerPhi is a user defined function that does Euler's Totient function)

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Or is there a better way to sum up this from i=1-24 such that

```
=1/A5*SUMPRODUCT((IF(FLOOR((GCD(A5,B4)/i),1)=GCD(A5,B4)/i,1,0)*EulerPhi(i)*COMBIN(A5/i,B4/i)))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is EulerPHI located?  It must be in a module attached to the workbook from which you are calling it, or you need to include the workbook name.

Comment: I put it in a visual basic module while working in this work book. The function comes up as a suggestion but does not seem to work beyond that.

Comment: What is the name of the visual basic module? If the name of the module is the same as the name of the function, you will get that error.  You can either rename the function, the module, or refer to it fully qualified as `EulerPhi.EulerPhi(ROW(1:24))`

Comment: Is this supposed to be an array function?  Why is 'ROW(1:24)` used in this way?

Answer (score 1):

The correct *answer* to your question *"what could be causing this"* is: **lack of troubleshooting**.

Asking why a formula isn't working, without sharing the data that it's looking at, or the code for custom functions, is like if I were to call you and say "what color is that thing?" ... You'd have no idea what I was asking (even though you *know* what colors *are*).

### Troubleshooting

Your question's title indicates that the problem is [SUMPRODUCT] or [ROW].  I can only assume **those terms were randomly chosen** since:

- you didn't indicate *why* you suspect those functions specifically
- explanation as to why those are any more of an issue than others in the formula like [ROW], [COMBIN] or even custom function [EulerPhi]
- you haven't checked back to answer questions about your post since a few minutes after posting.

> ### Troubleshooting Steps
>
> The five-step troubleshooting process consists of the following:
>   <sub>((More detail from the [source])(https://www.myodesie.com/wiki/index/returnEntry/id/2956#Troubleshooting%20Steps))</sub>
>
> 1. Verify that a problem actually exists.
> 2. Isolate the cause of the problem.
> 3. Correct the cause of the problem.
> 4. Verify that the problem has been corrected.
> 5. Follow up to prevent future problems.

You stopped at Step 1.  **Even if the next step *was***:

> 2. <del>Post the problematic line as a question on *Stack Overflow*.</del>

. . . you still couldn't expect a reliable solution since **nobody else** has the information required for steps 2,3 & 4.  (Also, this isn't SO's purpose.  Please see the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).)

### Isolating the Problem

*Normally, I wouldn't have spent this much time on an "unattended" Question, missing information required to solve the problem, but I'm documenting my troubleshooting steps and this works as a partial an example.*

**For the sake of illustration** I've broken this down into all 25 formula sections. <sub>(15 without repeats).</sub>  Obviously it's not necessary to go this extent, when checking such a simple formula.

[image: Troubleshooting Steps]

<sub>(Download a copy of the worksheet [here](http://jmp.sh/6wo4Lp6).)</sub>

Thus, I can't know for sure where the problem lies without knowing:
 - the value of `A5`
 - the value of `B5`
 - the contents of `ROW(1:24)`
 - the code behind custom function `EulerPhi`

. . . but I can almost guarantee it comes down to:
 1. The custom function `EulerPhi`, and
 2. Unintended effects of referring to range ROW(1:24).

You can confirm my theory by checking if this formula calculates properly:

```
=EulerPhi(ROW(1:24))
```

If that happens to be working as it should, then copy-and-paste the following 15 forumlas to a blank area of the *same worksheet* where the data is.  Your problem lies with the errors you get:

```
=1/A5*SUMPRODUCT((IF(FLOOR((GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24)),1)=GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24),1,0)*EulerPhi(ROW(1:24))*COMBIN(A5/ROW(1:24),B4/ROW(1:24))))
=A5*SUMPRODUCT((IF(FLOOR((GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24)),1)=GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24),1,0)*EulerPhi(ROW(1:24))*COMBIN(A5/ROW(1:24),B4/ROW(1:24))))
=SUMPRODUCT((IF(FLOOR((GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24)),1)=GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24),1,0)*EulerPhi(ROW(1:24))*COMBIN(A5/ROW(1:24),B4/ROW(1:24))))
=(IF(FLOOR((GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24)),1)=GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24),1,0)*EulerPhi(ROW(1:24))*COMBIN(A5/ROW(1:24),B4/ROW(1:24)))
=IF(FLOOR((GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24)),1)=GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24),1,0)*EulerPhi(ROW(1:24))*COMBIN(A5/ROW(1:24),B4/ROW(1:24))
=IF(FLOOR((GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24)),1)=GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24),1,0)
=FLOOR((GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24)),1)
=GCD(A5,B4)/ROW(1:24)
=GCD(A5,B4)
=EulerPhi(ROW(1:24))
=COMBIN(A5/ROW(1:24),B4/ROW(1:24))
=A5
=B4/ROW(1:24)
=B4
=ROW(1:24)
```

(The formulas were just copies from the image, with duplicates removed.)

By this point, you will have either solved the problem, or at least, have a **specific question** to ask.  Please, read tips on what example information needs to be included here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Proper troubleshooting methods seem time consuming but the elimination process gets quicker with practice, and will save a lot of time and frustration (for yourself and others) in the long run.